# How to pass parameter in another method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

So I have a method.

```
def func(y,t,a):
    z=y
    dydt=[t*z+a] 
    return dydt
```

I want to use this method in other function like this:

```
def main_func(func,arg=()):
    sol=func(1,2,arg[0])
    return sol
a=1
main_func(func,arg=(a))
```

It works but It will not work with the method which is like that

```
def new_func(y,t,a,b):
    z=y
    dydt=[t*z+a+b] 
    return dydt
a=1
b=2
main_func(new_func,arg=(a,b))
```

Got the error: `TypeError: new_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'`

So, I have only thing to modify `main_func`.But I want to generalised the the function `main_func` for work with any function so that it will take other parameters `func(y,t,a, b,.....)`

Comment: In the last line, you are calling a new_func without any argument.

Comment: If I use arg[1] in main func then it will work . but I want to use with more param .Every time I do not want to add extra parameter in func of main_func.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpacking only works with iterables like list,tuple etc. So to pass a single argument you need to pass it as:

`main_func(func,arg=(a,))` OR `main_func(func,arg=[a])`

Just parenthesis over values are not considered tuples, so `(a)` is treated as `a` and is not a tuple.

To make it a tuple just add an extra `,` after a like : `(a,)`

That said,

You can use unpacking operator `*` like so,

```
def func(y,t,a):
    z=y
    dydt=[t*z+a] 
    return dydt

def new_func(y,t,a,b):
    z=y
    dydt=[t*z+a+b] 
    return dydt

def main_func(func,arg=()):
    sol=func(1,2,*arg)
    return sol
```

Output:

```
>>> a=1
>>> main_func(func,arg=(a,))
[3]

>>> a=1
>>> b=2
>>> main_func(new_func,arg=(a,b))
[5]
```

**EDIT**:
If you don't want the arg argument to be an empty tuple in particular when no arguments are passed, you can keep `*args` as argument in `main_func`:

```
def main_func(func,*args):
    sol=func(1,2,*args)
    return sol
```

Output:

```
>>> a=1
>>> main_func(func,a)
[3]

>>> a,b=1,2
>>> main_func(new_func,a,b)
[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because new_func has an extra argument, b, so in your main_func, change how func is called:

```
def main_func(func,arg=()):
    sol=func(1,2,*arg)#or func(1,2,arg[0],arg[1])
    return sol

a=1
main_func(new_func,arg=(a,))#add an extra comma if there is only 1 item to tell python it is a tuple, or use a list like [a]
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the code and I think it may be the answer that you are looking for. THERE IS LOT OF MISTAKES IN YOUR CODE ABOVE.

my code:

```
def func(y,t,a):
    z=y
    #it return a list but I think it is intended to return a integer
    #dydt=[t*z+a] 
    #dydt = t*z+a
    return (t*z+a)

#got value of function when called this function
#we do not need func as argument
def main_func(arg):
    return (func(1,2,arg))

a=1
#using a not arg=(0)
#passing argument in function that you did not passed

main_func(func(1,2,a))

def new_func(y,t,a,b):
    z=y
    #dydt=[t*z+a+b] 
    return (t*z+a+b)
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4


print (main_func(new_func(a,b,c,d)))
```